# How to refresh wpf text binding loaded from Singleton?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, singleton

I have a singleton class that has `LanguageModel` in it and i have already done text binding using following code

```
{Binding Source={StaticResource Language}, Path=Language.HeaderText}
```

how i want to update this value at runtime. Can anyone suggest me how do I update this in runtime? Where "`Language`" is inside a singleton class.

Comment: @Clemens Do i need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged to the model class itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF UI updates are built on INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. For whichever properties you want to see an update you would need to trigger NotifyPropertyChanged event.

If you don't want to touch your Language model with 200 members. Identify the properties for which you want to see the updates and move them to a ViewModel and implement the NotifyPropertyChanged within ViewModel. But mind that, this will only reflect if you are updating the Value from ViewModel. If the Langauge model gets directly updated it won't notify the ViewModel which inturn wont notify the UI.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

If your class implements this interface the bindings will update automatically when you change the property value.

Follow the documentation to implement the interface, but basically you'll need to notify the subscribers of your property that it has changed. You can do this by calling `NotifyPropertyChanged()` in the setter of your `HeaderText` property.

**Simplified code, you need to implement the actual interface as well:**

```
public class Language : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private string _headerText;

    public string HeaderText {
        get {
            return _headerText;
        }

        set {
            if (value != _headerText) {
                _headerText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you please suggest me, if there is any quick way to triggering PropertyChanged Event to all members in my Model. There are around 200 members in my model. It would be very hectic task to improve my model.

Comment: @ChandanGupta: As explained in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx): "The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I have done this, but still there is problem. Is it due to I am implementing this in PCL?

Comment: I resolved it. I was missing "Mode=TwoWay" in the binding.
   

    {Binding Source={StaticResource Language}, Path=Language.HeaderText, Mode=TwoWay}

Thanks for your help guys. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. I was missing "Mode=TwoWay" in the binding.

```
{Binding Source={StaticResource Language}, Path=Language.HeaderText, Mode=TwoWay}
```

Thanks for your help guys. Really appreciated.